# R caret / How does cross-validation for train within rfe work

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, rfe

I have a question regarding the `rfe` function from the `caret` library. On the caret-homepage [link](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/featureselection.html) they give the following RFE algorithm: 
[algorithm](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/Algo2.png)

For this example I am using the `rfe` function with 3-fold cross-validation and the *train* function with a linear-SVM and 5-fold cross-validation.

```
library(kernlab)
library(caret)
data(iris)

# parameters for the tune function, used for fitting the svm
trControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# parameters for the RFE function
rfeControl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, method = "cv",
                     number= 4, verbose = FALSE )

rf1 <- rfe(as.matrix(iris[,1:4]), as.factor(iris[,5]) ,sizes = c( 2,3) ,  
           rfeControl = rfeControl, trControl = trControl, method = "svmLinear")
```

- From the algorithm above I assumed that the algorithm would work with 2 nested cross-validations:

  1. `rfe` would split the data (150 samples) into 3 folds
  2. the `train` function would be run on the training-set (100 samples) with 5 fold cross validation to tune the model parameters - with subsequent RFE.

What confuses me is that when I take a look on the results of the `rfe` function:

```
> lapply(rf1$control$index, length)
$Fold1
[1] 100
$Fold2
[1] 101
$Fold3
[1] 99

> lapply(rf1$fit$control$index, length)
$Fold1
[1] 120
$Fold2
[1] 120
$Fold3
[1] 120
$Fold4
[1] 120
$Fold5
[1] 120
```

From that it appears that the size of the training sets from the 5-fold cv is 120 samples when I would expect a size of 80. ??

So it would be great if someone could clarify how *rfe* and *train* work together.

Cheers

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pROC_1.5.4      e1071_1.6-1     class_7.3-5     caret_5.15-048 
 [5] foreach_1.4.0   cluster_1.14.3  plyr_1.7.1      reshape2_1.2.1 
 [9] lattice_0.20-10 kernlab_0.9-15 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_2.15.1 grid_2.15.1     iterators_1.0.6
 [5] stringr_0.6.1   tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: 5-fold CV leaves out one fifth of the data set for each CV arm. Therefore, you train on 120 each time and the test set is the remaining 30 samples. 30 samples * 5 = 150 samples.

Comment: Yes, but according to the description of the algorithm the 5-fold-CV should be applied on the training data resulting from a 3-fold-cv. So therefore 1st training set = 150/3 * 2, 2nd 100/5 * 4 = 80.

Comment: @Fabian_G did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue, and was considering contacting topepo or filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `lapply(rf1$fit$control$index, length)` does not store what we think it does.

For me to understand that it was necessary to look into the code. What happens there is the following:

When you call `rfe` the whole data is passed to the `nominalRfeWorkflow`.

In `nominalRfeWorkflow`, the train and test data splitted according to `rfeControl` (in our example 3 times according to the 3-folded CV rule) is passed to `rfeIter`. 
These splits we can find in our result under `rf1$control$index`.

In `rfeIter` the ~100 training samples (our example) are used to find the final variables (which is the output of that function). 
As I understand it, the ~50 test samples (our example) are used to calculate the performance for the different variable sets but they are only stored as external performance but not used to select the final variables. 
For selecting these the performance estimates of the 5 fold cross validation are used.
But we cannot find these indices in the final result returned by `rfe`. 
If we really need them, we need to fetch them from `fitObject$control$index` in `rfeIter`, return them to `nominalRfeWorkflow`, then to `rfe` and from there in the resulting `rfe`-Class object returned by `rfe`.

So what is stored in `lapply(rf1$fit$control$index, length)`? - When `rfe` found the best variables the final model fit is created with the best variables and the full reference data (150). `rf1$fit` is created in `rfe` as follows:

`fit <- rfeControl$functions$fit(x[, bestVar, drop = FALSE],
                                 y,
                                 first = FALSE,
                                 last = TRUE,
                                 ...)`

This function is again runs the `train` function and does a final cross validation with the full reference data, the final feature set and `trControl` given via the ellipses (`...`). 
Since our `trControl` is supposed to do 5 fold CV it is thus correct that `lapply(rf1$fit$control$index, length)` returns 120 since we have to calculate 150/5*4=120.

Comment: can you point to caret's docs or code where it says that the `rfeControl$functions$fit` runs `train`? @ben